# Should we need to consider time dilation effect when travel in a very fast rocket?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

How long does it take for a rocket to reach a planet 10 light years away if the rocket's speed is just near the light speed?

If the speed is 1 *c*, the folks will answer it will take 10 year to travel to the planet.

```
Rocket Speed      Travel Time (without time dilation)
1c                10 years
```

That is correct for the clock on the earth.

But, due to the time dilation effect, the clock of the rocket will be much slower and the astronauts in the rocket will then take much less time to travel to the planet. Is it correct?

```
Rocket Speed      Lorentz Contraction       Travel Time
0.9c              0.436                     4.36 years
0.99c             0.141                     1.41 years
0.999c            0.045                     159 days (0.45 years)
```

The human life is about 100 years. So, does it means we can travel much more than 100 light-year distance if there is a near-light-speed rocket?

Comment: Hi Cray, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Could you elaborate on why you think it might not be the case?

Comment: @DavidZ I am a folk and just have knowledge as most of folks. Just feel so weird, if astronauts' clock pass only 159 days, how can they move 10 light year distance from earth?